# Line graph generated based on given parameter SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, linegraph

I have a line graph for the query below.

```
Select Date
      ,Time
      ,MaxValue
      ,MinValue
from MyTabl
where product = @Product
  and (Date between @FromDate and @ToDate)
```

For Line Graph, add one parameter `Interval(Values - 2, 4 ,8, 12, 24)`.

I want to show line graph data points differently based on the parameters selection.

Now, it return 50 rows where in line graph I mapped x-axis for `date,time`, y-axis for `MaxValue`. It remain shows the same graph for all interval

How can I include Interval Values in linegraph, so that graph displays based on interval values?

[image: LineGraph]

Comment: You will need to show the current results and the results you want to see, as your question is not clear.

Comment: You have still not explained what change you are expecting to see.  Where are you using the `Inteval` parameter value?  How do you want the value to affect the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already tried going to Horizontal Axis Property of your chart?
There's an interval property in there under Axis Options tab. Just click the expression icon then put your Parameter in the expression like this `Parameters!ParameterName.Value`

Comment: I did this already. Is there any need to assign any other values?

Comment: Hmm maybe try to play around with the Interval type? Try to set that into Number?